# Rails Test::Unit test of model validation surprisingly slow – I18n?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, minitest

I have a simple test in my Rails app which is consistently taking much longer than other apparently similar tests.

It takes 1 to 2 seconds of real time to run `test_invalid_without_name` as below:

```
VALID_PARAMS = { name: 'Client record' }

def test_invalid_without_name
  c = Client.new(VALID_PARAMS)
  c.name = nil
  refute c.valid?, 'should not be valid without a name'
end
```

The next test, `test_valid_with_all_params` takes less than 1/100th of a second:

```
def test_valid_with_all_params
  c = Client.new(VALID_PARAMS)
  assert c.valid?, 'should be valid with appropriate parameters'
end
```

The Client model is totally straightforward at this stage:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :entity, polymorphic: true

  validates :name, presence: true

end
```

Can anyone either spot what’s wrong here, or give me an idea where I should look next to try to figure this out?

**Update 1**

I have used [ruby-prof](http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/) to profile the code, and it seems much of the time is being spent in the [Psych](http://rubygems.org/gems/psych) gem. I believe this is used in [`ActiveRecord::..#serialize`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize), which I am using in another model as follows:

```
class Opportunity < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :client 
   serialize :details, Hash
end
```

However, removing the call to `serialize` here doesn’t make any difference to the Client tests (and I can’t see why it would, the two classes are associated, but no Opportunities are instantiated in the Client test).

**Update 2**

Turns out Psych is being called because I18n is using it. My assumption at this point is that the failed validation causes I18n to go to the locale files to pull out an error message. I will look into stubbing out I18n for testing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out a suitable approach to solving this was to use ruby-prof as follows.

Add to Gemfile (in the `development` group):

```
gem 'ruby-prof'
```

Wrap the test code in calls to the profiler:

```
def test_invalid_without_name
  RubyProf.start

  cr = Client.new(VALID_PARAMS)
  cr.name = nil
  refute cr.valid?, 'should not be valid without a name'

  result = RubyProf.stop
  printer = RubyProf::CallStackPrinter.new(result)
  printer.print(File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'profile_invalid_without_name.html'), 'w'))
end
```

This will create an interactive HTML document at the root of your Rails app, which shows the breakdown of where the time is spent.

In this case, it was 80%+ in I18n looking for translations. I added the following line to `config/environments/test.rb` to stub it out in testing:

```
  I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::KeyValue.new({})
```

I will probably make the following additional improvements in future:

1. Be more specific with where I stub out I18n, so that full-stack acceptance tests can use the real thing.
2. Write a more convenient profiling approach. It looks like ruby-prof offers various other mechanisms for activating it, this was just the simplest for initial use.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to answer the question without more information.

- Does this happen when you run the each of tests individually?
- Do you have anything in the setup/teardown or your test_helper.rb?
- Does it happen if you pass a hash with name => nil instead of setting it?
- Did you redefine the name setter?
- Do you have any callbacks on your model?

Comment: Hi, some good suggestions here, thanks. I did not redefine the setter or add any callbacks, and there is no setup/teardown: all the code / test code is above. As you suggest, I have now tried running each test one by one, and the behaviour for both slow and fast tests is the same. I have also tried setting a hash with `name: nil`, or not passing any parameters to `new` but again there was no difference in timing.